# How to use as_json to use a method within an association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Imagine I have the following Models:

```
class Voice
  include Mongoid::Document
  ...
  has_and_belongs_to_many :productions
  ...
  def define_user_currency
  ...
  end
end

class Production
  include Mongoid::Document
  ...
  has_and_belongs_to_many :voices
  ...
  def production_currency
  ...
  end
end
```

I'd like to get all `Voices` including all productions and call the `define_user_currency` on each `Voice` as well as `production_currency` on each Production. I've tried the following (I've added this method on `Voice`):

```
def_custom_format
  self.as_json(
    method: self.define_user_currency(currency, ip),
    include: [:builder_types, :voice_types, :preferences, :languages, :productions => {:methods => production_currency(currency, ip)}],
    except: [:avatar_content_type, :avatar_file_size, :avatar_file_name, :avatar_fingerprint, :avatar_updated_at, :voice_content_type, :voice_file_size, :voice_fingerprint, 
    :voice_updated_at, :artist_id, :price_per_word_GBP, :price_per_word_EUR, :price_per_word_USD, :price_GBP, :price_EUR, :price_USD, :categories_name, :category_ids, :production_ids, 
    :language_ids, :preference_ids, :voice_type_ids, :builder_type_ids]
  )
end
```

But `Production` is not coming within `Voice` and I get `Undefined method production_currency`. If I try `include: [:builder_types, :voice_types, :preferences, :languages, :productions => {:methods => self.production_currency(currency, ip)}],` I get the same result.

How can I apply the `production_method` on each production?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be possible if your method `production_currency(currency, ip)` did not take any arguments. Its not possible to send aruguements as there is no way to send comma separated values like

```
methods: :production_currency, currency, ip
# or
methods: "production_currency(#{currency},#{ip})"
```

See code

```
 Array(options[:methods]).each { |m| hash[m.to_s] = send(m) if respond_to?(m) }
```

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5b368010f64106f7b87a4306b41adcefa856ab67/activemodel/lib/active_model/serialization.rb#L110

Why don't you try this. Make `production_currency` gather required info from association it self. like

```
def production_currency
  currency = self.voice.currency
  ip = self.voice.ip
end
```

and

```
:productions => {:methods => :production_currency}
```

Comment: I did as you've suggested (removed the arguments form the method) and tried again, but what happened is I didn't get the error, but nothing happened either (I got no `productions` data whatsoever. It was like I haven't included the `:productions`

Comment: May be there is no production data for that relation

Comment: To be honest, after quite a bit of struggle I've found a solution. I do need to point out that you were almost right. The solution was using a method without args, but the structure was slightly different: `include: {productions:{method:production_currency}}`

Comment: Are you sure with this `{productions:{method:production_currency}}`, I doubt :)